# BASH error, unexpected token near "source"

Tags: linux, bash

Hoping someone can help me figure out the cause of this error:

```
-bash: /Users/me/.bash_profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `source'
-bash: /Users/me/.bash_profile: line 1: `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi source /Users/me/.bash_profile'
```

Here is the line in my `.bash_profile`:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi source /Users/me/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Try a semicolon betwen `fi` and `source`

Comment: Are you really sourcing `/Users/me/.bash_profile` from within the same file? That's going to lead to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

You missed a semicolon after `fi`:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi; source /Users/me/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your .bash_profile

it should look like this

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

Should end after the fi.

The source `/Users/me/.bash_profile` is a command that you should run after editing the bash profile. Just erase this after the fi and everything just run fine.